# Stripe payment method not working in shopify

Tags: e-commerce, stripe-payments, shopify

In my Shopify store, i have set Stripe payment method. But when I enter test card entry always given errors. Like "card declined", "Not matched", "transaction failed" etc. I have used multiple card numbers Visa card and Master card.

> Using test card number from here [link](https://stripe.com/docs/testing#cards)
>
> Stripe account is in test mode.

Any suggestion, please.
Thanks

Comment: Any one can give me answer? Rather then updating small questions update?

Answer (score 0):

Shopify has its demo own payment gateway called the 'bogus payment gateway' in which you can test that your payments are going through correctly.

Through Shopify's docs in the link I provided you will find test card numbers which you can use to make sure your payments are working!

More detailed info can be found here
https://help.shopify.com/manual/sell-online/checkout-settings/test-orders